# ES6 Map features support - too big support in IE11?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm exploring ES6 few features. To check what is available and where I use:

http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

To play around I use Babel:

https://babeljs.io/repl

When exploring `Map` , compatibility table says that

> constructor arguments are not supported in IE11

But I copied sample code:

```
var result = function() {
  var key1 = {};
  var key2 = {};
  var map = new Map([[key1, 123], [key2, 456]]);

  return map.has(key1) && map.get(key1) === 123 &&
         map.has(key2) && map.get(key2) === 456;
}();

console.log(result);
```

executed it in IE11 and to my surprise, result is **true**. **true** was both in Babel (although Babel didn't generate any code) and also in IE 11 console.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To play around I use Babel:
>
> https://babeljs.io/repl

That's Babel using its `Map` polyfill in the REPL. If you run that code, verbatim, in IE11 itself, you get `false`, not `true`:

```js
var result = function() {
  var key1 = {};
  var key2 = {};
  var map = new Map([[key1, 123], [key2, 456]]);

  return map.has(key1) && map.get(key1) === 123 &&
         map.has(key2) && map.get(key2) === 456;
}();

console.log(result);
```

Result in IE11:

[image]

---

*(I was briefly thrown by the fact that in the REPL, if you `console.log(Map)`, it shows `function Map() { [native code] }`. But [logansfmyth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785065/loganfsmyth) was kind enough to confirm in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38856196/es6-map-features-support-too-big-support-in-ie11/38856267?noredirect=1#comment65078065_38856267) that Babel does that with shimmed functions if they conform to native behavior.)*

Comment: Thanks. I tested it here and you're right. But still, if I open Babel's page and run it in multiline mode result is true. So it means that Babel is using shim. Quite misleading

Comment: @dragonfly: Well, the REPL is meant to give you a quick environment for testing what you'll get if you transpile with Babel. But I have to say I'm not quite sure what they're doing, exactly, to make it work; see the update at the end of the answer... :-)

Comment: Babel does indeed polyfill this. The `[native code]` is a debatable thing, but `core-js` at the moment does that to make things look native if they have the native behavior.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: Thank you, that makes sense. I should have had the sense not to trust the `toString` of a function!

Comment: @loganfsmyth: so does it mean that when I include babel in my build pipeline I also need to include whole core-js?

Comment: `core-js` is part of `babel-polyfill`, so it will be included when you load `babel-polyfill`.